Proving a property of simplices
I am trying to prove the following: Let $\sigma$ be a simplex, $y \in \mathrm{Int}(\sigma)$ and $x_1 \neq x_2 \in \mathrm{Bd}(\sigma)$. Then the open segments $(y, x_1)$ and $(y, x_2)$ do not intersect.
It is part of an exercise whose first part (which I have been able to prove) asks to show that under the previous assumptions, $(y, x_2) \subset \mathrm{Int}(\sigma)$.
It "looks" obvious if I draw some pictures, but I can't figure out a rigorous proof. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Hint: Extend the segments to lines. Then use what you know about the ways in which two lines in Euclidean space can intersect.

I had thought about that: if they intersect at some point, say $z$, the segment $(y,z)$ should be contained in both $(y, x_1)$ and $(y, x_2)$, so the line passing through $y$ and $x_1$ should be the same as the line passing though $y$ and $x_2$. Then if I can show that the half-line connecting $y$ and $z$ intersects $\mathrm{Bd}(\sigma)$ in a single point, then $x_1 = x_2$ and I will have a contradiction. However, I am stuck with that last part. It seems obvious again, but I don't know how to prove it.

@Sergio Here's what I was trying to get at: You already know the lines intersect in $y$, so either that's the only point of intersection or the two lines are equal. Then you can proceed by cases. At one point you will have to use that a ray emanating from an interior point of the simplex only hits the boundary in exactly one point. This is a consequence of the convexity + compactness of $\sigma$.
